# 5 boxes not centering correctly in the center of the page

Tags: html, css, centering

I am totally new into programming. I've aligned 5 boxed **horizontally** , but what I want is to center the boxes. The boxes should also be responsive what they are right now. I am searching and searching for how to center a div, but as result I get 
 `margin: 0 auto; width: 800px;`. When I adjust my browser to 100%, the 5th box get under the other boxes.

```css
.square { 
 float:left;
 width: 12.5vw;
    height: 12.5vw;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
 border: 0.5px solid red;
 text-align: center; 
}

.square span {
 font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="outside">
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.7</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to remove the floating from the inner divs, and display them as inline blocks instead. The outside would have the auto margins and a center text aligning, like this:

```css
.outside {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square { 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 12.5vw;
  height: 12.5vw;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
 border: 0.5px solid red;
 text-align: center;
}

.square span {
 font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="square">
    <span>2.1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <span>2.3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <span>2.5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <span>2.6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <span>2.7</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `max-width` or `width` to the parent container. Then center it with `margin: 0 auto`. Of course set the `width` of the parent element to you needs. I just set it to `520px` as an example.

**W3Schools says this:**

> Center Align Elements To horizontally center a block element (like ), use `margin: auto;`
>
> Setting the width of the element will prevent it from stretching out
>   to the edges of its container.
>
> The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining
>   space will be split equally between the two margins:

***See example below.***

```css
.outside {
  max-width: 520px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square { 
 float:left;
 width: 12.5vw;
    height: 12.5vw;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
 border: 0.5px solid red;
 text-align: center; 
}

.square span {
 font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <span>2.7</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In a small window it works fine, but I had the same issue when you make your browser 100%. The boxes are getting underneath the other boxes.

Comment: You will get that problem no matter what you do. Make them responsive. `inline-block`, `text-align: center`they will all break when window gets to small

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align` `center` for `outside`

```
.outside{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Remove `float` & add `display` `inline-block` `square`

```
.square{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 12.5vw;
    height: 12.5vw;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 0.5px solid red;
    text-align: center; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your requirement entirely but try the following. It will center your boxes and also won't allow them to wrap to next line on reducing the resolution.

Replace your css with:

```
.square { 
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 12.5vw;
    margin-right: 1%;
    position: relative;
    border: 0.5px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.square span {
    font-size: 3vw;
}

.outside {
    width: 100%;
}

.inside {
    width: 69%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Html with:

```
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
        <div class="square">
            <span>2.1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>2.3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>2.5</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>2.6</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>2.7</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```